# ¿Como utilizar en android studio el gradle que se instala en linux?

Tags: android, linux, gradle

Instalé el gradle que està en el repositorio de linux 9. Cómo lo puedo utilizar desde el android studio para no utilizar el que trae android studio?
saludos